# How to make concurrent threaded requests to test response time of list of URLs in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests

i am writing a python script for request testing (i am a beginner at this) where i have a list of urls that i want to test using multiple concurrent requests for ex if i have 10 urls and 100 input number of threads then 100 independent connections should be made and they should access those urls randomly and in the end return average response time of each url.

```
out = []
CONNECTIONS = 100
TIMEOUT = 50
json_str=[]
tlds = open('sampleurl.txt').read().splitlines()

for data in tlds:
    json_str.append(''.join(data ))


def load_url(data, timeout):

    response = requests.post('http://example.com', headers=headers,data=data,timeout=timeout)
    return response.status_code

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=CONNECTIONS) as executor:
    future_to_url = (executor.submit(load_url, data, TIMEOUT) for data in json_str)
    time1 = time.time()

    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):

        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            data = str(type(exc))
        finally:
            out.append(data)
    time2 = time.time()

print(f'Took {time2-time1:.2f} s')

print(pd.Series(out).value_counts())
```

i tried this but it stops after testing each url only once. i want the code to continue running and open the url multiple times until all connections are exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see what the json will store but since it stores data, you are processing each request only once using this piece of code

```
future_to_url = (executor.submit(load_url, data, TIMEOUT) for data in json_str)
```

but you want that job to be submitted to executor service multiple times then you can create a loop around it and make it run multiple times.

```
while count < 10:
    count += 1
    future_to_url = (executor.submit(load_url, data, TIMEOUT) for data in json_str)
```

This will submit multiple requests to the Executor service.